# how to run the javascript function in the .post() output data recieved from a php echoed page

Tags: php, javascript, runtime, output, .post

I loaded new data at my web page runtime by calling x.php I retrieve html and javascript dynamically generated. But the javascripts functions did not run.

**code in index page, call php page:**

```
$.post('x.php', {
    id: num
}, function (output) {
    document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = output;
});
```

**sample html**

```
<div id='view2'></div>
```

**sample of *output* js functions:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(y, s) {
        id + y / s
    }

    function v(d) {
        document.getElementById('view2').innerHTML = d;
    }
</script>
```

*how do I make the new JavaScript functions in the output data run along with earlier js loaded? other functions will depend on this new generated function*

Comment: thanks I noted some typos errors

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve JS from a Post/Get, not using  the js at the response needs to be evaluated using eval. 
I mean the JS is not evaluated automatically, so that you need to perform manually

```
$.post('x.php', {
    id: num
}, function (output) {
    eval(output);
}
```

the output shall be pure js and additionally, is not secure **use eval** :)

Comment: thanks. I separated my output js from php and used the eval() it worked. I will use this until i come up with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned javascript needs to be called by whatever javascript is there on the page ;)

You might try putting:

```
a(y,s);
v(d);
```

after your function declarations up there.  When you put "function" before the js it's like you're declaring a variable:

```
var x;
```

Also, your ids are mismatched currently (view vs view2), I suspect that may be just a typo though.